# Can't dismiss UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I have a UIAlertController that pops up if there is no internet connection. I don't know how to properly dismiss it when the connection is back. As I keep checking for it every 10 sec, if I do :

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

this will dismiss the main view at every interval once the alert view was already dismissed. I tried:

```
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        print("Internet connection OK")

        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        print("Internet connection FAILED")

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

but `alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` doesn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can show another view controller saying that there _is_ internet connection and the user can just dismiss them?

Comment: i think the issue can be you are trying to dismiss the alert before you have show the alert

Answer (score 1):

I think , the issue is presenting the **UIAlertController** more than one time and try to dismiss one instance of UIAlertController .. so you need to dismiss the UIAlertController before present it like below

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        print("Internet connection OK")

        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        print("Internet connection FAILED")
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: hmm I see what you mean! but dismissing it before presenting doesn't work.

Comment: Increase the time interval 10 sec to 30 sec and check it.. Otherwise you can use a single instance  UIAlertController and try it to present and dismiss without animation e.g. alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

Comment: I did not press down vote at all! That wasn't me. :s Edit: Sorry,I figured that when I try to up vote, it down votes somehow, so I undid that

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: Thank you @OS_Binod and @Pyro

```
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        print("Internet connection OK")

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

    } else {
        print("Internet connection FAILED")
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue can be you are trying to dismiss the alert before you have show the alert

**Update:**
if you want to dismiss the alert only after internet is back keep the reference of the 'UIAlertController' after it has shown once you can dismiss it with that object

In your case you are trying to dismiss 'alert' of the newly created object which not even shown so you need to dismiss the old one which is kept in reference before creating new one when internet is back

Also if you are calling the method every 10 sec dismiss the older alert before presenting the new one to avoid the multiple alert else you can make a flag if alert is already displayed method will not check again every 10 sec till alert is dismiss

better option will be: 
check the internet connect outside and if no internet connection then only create UIAlertController

**Update 1** You can make alert as global variable and store the alert object when you create that in the else block and when the internet is back you can check if alert has object if yes you can dismiss the alert

```
 if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        print("Internet connection OK")
        if alert != nil {
          alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) 
        }
     //dismiss the alert using old refence from the alert
    //continue your normal code
    } else { 
       alert = UIAlertController(title: "No internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
       //you may check and dismiss the previous alertcontroller before presenting the new one
       print("Internet connection FAILED")
       self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: thanks! but i don't want the user to be able to dismiss the alert on pressing ok unless the connection is back.

Comment: but you can't dismiss alert before declaring it in the else block

Comment: Thank you! But you can't check for alert != nil before you declare it.

Comment: in the previous edit(update 1) i have written it to make the variable global so you can declar it at top of your viewcontroller so it will be accessible in both the block , if you need i can update with the additional code

Comment: oh i see! but why do you redeclare it in the else bock? that way the if block will not be dismissing the same alert instance, no?

Comment: sorry for the mistake i have remove that local declaration